# Select By Location in ArcGIS using C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-9.3

I am creating a tool which the user will select point or line features from the map and it will display their names in a list then after clicking on any of these features from the list, it will show the intersected polygons in another list.

The problem that I don't know how to do a `SpatialFilter` to do this intersecting functionality, which it will be done like the one in the `Select By Location` tool.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please have a look [IFeatureClass.Search Method](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/arcobjects/esriGeoDatabase/IFeatureClass_Search.htm)

To get feature by mouse click:

```
public List<IFeature> Search(IPoint mousePoint, double buffer, IFeatureClass featureClass)
{
    var envelope = mousePoint.Envelope;
    envelope.Expand(buffer, buffer, false);
    var geodataset = (IGeoDataset)featureClass;
    string shapeFieldName = featureClass.ShapeFieldName;
    Geodatabase.ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new Geodatabase.SpatialFilter();
    spatialFilter.Geometry = envelope;
    spatialFilter.SpatialRel = esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelCrosses;
    spatialFilter.set_OutputSpatialReference(shapeFieldName, geodataset.SpatialReference);

    Geodatabase.IFeatureCursor featureCursor = ArcFeatureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);

    var features = new List<IFeature>();
    Geodatabase.IFeature feature;
    while ((feature = featureCursor.NextFeature()) != null)
        features.Add(new Feature(feature));
    return features;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check this now but I am wondering about what `spatialFilter.set_OutputSpatialReference` does ?

Comment: It sets spatial reference for Query

Comment: I am working on it and I have some issues one of them that I am not using envelop because I have the ObjectId of the (point/line) feature and I have to get the intesection through this Id

Comment: Is it like, you have a feature and you need other features that are at the same location?

Comment: Thanks very much, your answer helped me a lot to find out the answer.